# ram keeps on filling when program is abruptly closed in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, stack-overflow

MAT-lab keeps on acquiring images form video object when program is closed abruptly,is there any way to know whether my program has been stopped abruptly?

it only stops when i type stop(vid), condition: the vid object must be there in work space
if you have cleared vid object by clear all , then MAT-LAB keeps on acquiring image from the camera

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is this: You have some matlab code that acquires data from a camera. If your code exits before getting to the point at which you order the camera to stop acquiring data, then the camera keeps going until your RAM is full Please correct me if I'm wrong. If I'm right, I'd advise you use try/catch statements as follows:

```
start(vid);
try
    %some code to use the video data
    stop(vid);
catch
    stop(vid);
end
```

Everything inside 'try' will run, and when it has finished, the video capture will be terminated. If something goes wrong and throws an error before it has got as far as the `stop(vid);` command, then rather than stalling the program it will display the error in the matlab prompt, and then jump to execute any code inside 'catch'. This means that if your code ends suddenly, the `stop(vid);` command is still run, and you don't run out of RAM.